# How to implement a Dialog with a search box?

Tags: android, search, android-alertdialog

I have a main activity with a list and a method that receives a keyword to make a search in the database.

I want to implement an `AlertDialog` with a search box that should appear on the main activity when I click a button through an action listener in this form

```
OnClickListener searchListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

This dialog should have a simply `EditText` box and two buttons (<kbd>Search</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd>), and have to pass the `String` picked by the `EditText` to a search method in the form:

```
public void searchWord(String keyword){
    // ....search in DB
    // ...updateListGUIWithNewValues()
}
```

This method is in the main activity to get the new list values so the activity can update the GUI list.

I have already implemented the search method and the main activity but I don't know the right way to implement this kind of dialog.

Comment: Here is [Search overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html). I think it is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my alert dialog code, which features an edit text.  I call it within a button click listener, so it is not a separate method. I found it somewhere on this site last week, but I can't seem to find it so i can cite it.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alert.setTitle("Manual Item Search");
alert.setMessage("Input Search Query");
// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(context);
alert.setView(input);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    String result = input.getText().toString();
        //do what you want with your result
        }
    });
alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
         // Canceled.
        }
    });
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi try this tutorial to creating a Search dialog using alert dialog **[Click here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/)**

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

  alert.setTitle("Search Box");
  alert.setMessage("Message");

 // Set an EditText view to get user input 
 final EditText input = new EditText(this);
 alert.setView(input);

 alert.setPositiveButton("Search", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  String value = input.getText();
 // Do something with value!
   }
  });
  alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  // Canceled.
  }
 });

  alert.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

#### dialog XML

build this xml in your `layout` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Search" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Dialog class

This class to handle the dialog

```
class dialog extends Dialog {

    private StackQuestionActivity activity;
    private Button search, cancel;
    private EditText text;
    private dialog thisDialog;

    public dialog(StackQuestionActivity context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.activity = context;
        this.thisDialog = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialoge);
        getWindow().setLayout(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        initalize();
    }

    private void initalize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                thisDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String textString = text.getText().toString();
                activity.searchWord(textString);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

#### Your activity

this is your main activity , call the dialog class when the button is pressed:

```
package com.example.question;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class StackQuestionActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Button press;
    private StackQuestionActivity activity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.activity = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        press = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        press.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog yourDialog = new dialog(activity);
                yourDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void searchWord(String textString) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

this is the result
[image: CHECK]

Comment: thanks for the answer but doesn't work, the app crashes with a null pointer exception, there is some error when invoke the listener

Comment: @AndreaF no there is no error, I write the code in my eclipse and the image i give to you is the results, the exception in your code